# ¿Como utilizar los valores de un arreglo obtenidos de una consulta MySQL para realizar otra consulta MySQL?

Tags: php, array, codeigniter

Estoy utilizando CodeIgniter y lo estoy tratando de hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT Tabla1.id 
                                From Tabla1 INNER JOIN Tabla2 
                                ON Tabla1.id = Tabla2.id");

if($query->num_rows()>0){
            foreach ($query2->result_array() as $row){
            echo $row['id']."<br>";
            }
```

Hasta aqui si puedo obtener una lista con todos los id de la Tabla1 pero necesito comparar cada uno de esos id en la siguiente consulta, el problema es que no se como guardarlos.

```
SELECT Tabla1.campo1, Tabla1.campo2, Tabla1.campo3
                    From Tabla1, Tabla2, Tabla3
                    WHERE Tabla1.campo2= Tabla2.campo2 
                    AND Tabla2.campo3 = Tabla3.campo3 
                    AND Tabla2.campo3 = $row['id']
```

Comment: Que no sabes como guardar, el resultado de la nueva consulta o $row['MT']??

Comment: El problema era con `$row['MT']` pero ya lo puedo guardar asi: `$sql2 =$row['MT'];` pero ahora me surgio un nuevo problema, la nueva consulta solo utiliza el ultimo valor del arreglo, intente meterlo en un ciclo for pero no me sale, alguna idea?

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que crees un arreglo auxiliar y le coloques los elementos a través de array_push(), luego recorras ese arreglo y realizes la consulta con cada elemento del arreglo, aunque no se que quieres hacer, en la primera consulta solo haces un select del id de tabla1, pero no seleccionas ninguna columna 'MT', por lo que no se de donde obtienes `$row['MT']`.

Comment: @JuanPinzón si en realidad fue un error mio al escribir el ejemplo pero digamos que id=MT, es que en el arreglo obtengo 600 id´s diferentes por ejemplo(eso ya lo hace mi codigo) pero despues debo utilizar cada id para realizar una nueva consulta y obtener 600 registros que dependen de id el cual obtengo en el array

Answer (score 1):

la verdad no sé que locura quieres, pero espero esto te de una idea de como solucionar el tema con una sola consulta.

```
SELECT campos-requeridos
  FROM (
    SELECT Tabla1.id 
    FROM  Tabla1 
    INNER JOIN Tabla2 
    ON Tabla1.id = Tabla2.id
  ) AS SUB1
 INNER JOIN Tabla2 on Tabla1.campo2 = Tabla2.campo3
 INNER JOIN Tabla3 on Tabla3.campo2 = Tabla2.campo3
 WHERE tabla2.campo3 = SUB1.id
```

Quedo al pendiente.

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda, me marca error en SUB.id: columna desconocida, es el alias que nombras al final del select que esta entre parentesis?

Comment: Mirando la consulta claro no debe existir esa columna por que se llama sub1 no sub, pero seria mas fácil si compartes la consulta para tener una idea mas clara.

Comment: @GuillermoVargas mejor comparte tu estructura de la tabla y algo de datos para poder obtener una mejor respuesta a tu pregunta, yo también creo que todo lo puedes obtener desde el SQL.